# Get values from a particular row using Custom Code SSRS

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

i have a report with parameter is the year i can select a multiple value: for example i selected 2005,2006,2007

when i click in view report i get this result 
[image]

i added some custom code to add value in arraylist

```
Dim values As System.Collections.ArrayList
Function AddValue(ByVal newValue As Integer)
    If (values Is Nothing) Then
        values = New System.Collections.ArrayList()
    End If
    values.Add(newValue)
End Function
Public Function GetArray(Item as Integer)
     return values(Item)
End Function
```

i added my code in my matrice this is the result 
[image]

The first row i got the right anwer but the other rows are false answers  this is the resut what i need 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without RDL details regarding your expressions - it is difficult to answer your question.  What are your expected results? What is the exact input and output you are expecting? Please provide samples.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, it seems the issue is in your custom code. Once you return the result at the end of first row. The variable(called "result") keeps the "66" and it was never overwritten so that it always shows "66". In Reporting Services, it generates cells from left to right, top to bottom. So you need to pass the first column (HP, DELL, Acer) as argument in your function and use a variable (called "previous")to receive this value. Always do the judgment at the beginning of the function, if the passing argument is not equal to the "previous". You need to clear the "result" variable.